# No result on PHP value Mysqli stmt

Tags: php, database, mysqli

there's no result on my `sqli` request .. like empty data.. i'm pretty sure in my database there's much data

here's my code, correct me if i got mistake on my code

```
<?php
    // include db handler
class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'include/DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

        // destructor
        function __destruct() {

        }

    function getSliderList(){

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT cPID, image FROM sliderImage");
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0 ) {
            $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $response[] = $result;
            $stmt->close();
            echo json_encode($response);
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
    }
}

        $x = new DB_Functions();
        $user = $x->getSliderList();
        $response = Array();
        if($user){
                $user;
                return false;
        } else {
                $response['error'] = "Sorry an error occured. Our Problem, not you.";
                return true;
        }

?>
```

my DB request to connect

```
<?php
class DB_Connect {
    private $conn;

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'include/Config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

        // return database handler
        return $this->conn;
    }
}

?>
```

and `config.php` file

```
<?php

/**
 * Database config variables
 */
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "bxxx");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "xxxx");
define("DB_DATABASE", "xxxx");
?>
```

i want to put the result into array.. and send this data using `json_encode` to use it in my app...

Comment: do you have error reporting on ?

Comment: no, there's nothing result even an error ...

Comment: why do you prepare statement that doesn't take input

Comment: what is conn is it mysqli object ?

Comment: what does DB_Connect.php contain, what's the method connect from class DB_Connect, what does it return ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a prepared statement here, since you're not parameterizing any data. Try a simple query instead

```
$stmt = $this->conn->query("SELECT cPID, image FROM sliderImage");
$response = array();
while($result = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $response[] = $result;
}
echo json_encode($response);
return true;
```

Comment: i have 218 data in Table on DB ... but it only show 1 data.. i want put all data in array